# Run along the rows in Excel

Tags: c#, excel

I have new entries that go into the Excel table and I constantly want to run to the last row number but it does not work

excel.Row.Count() this the problem

```
for (int i = 0; i < excel.Row.Count(); i++)
{
    if (excel.ReadCall(i, 1).Equals(emailLogin.Text))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("WELCOME");//to meassege excel
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: More detail required, what package are you using?

Comment: What do you want to happen and what doesn't happen?

Comment: @leeTaylor to show message